# How to save card details using stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

How to save card details in stripe payment gateway and use card details for next payment for particular user who entered the card details before

thank you

Comment: Where are you stuck with this? It seems to be [documented](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards).

Answer (score 0):

Before saving card you need to create customer first like below

Right now I am giving you an example with PHP language.

Creating customer :

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
  'name' => 'Test User',
  'email' => 'cardtestuser@gmail.com',
  'description' => 'My First Test Customer',
]);
```

You can refer the link for more detail : https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

It will return the object with customer id e.g : `cust_****` that you need to keep with you for later used else you can get it from Stripe dashboard.

Now we need to generate token for the card that we need to add to the customer that recently created in stripe

```
$token = \Stripe\Token::create([
  'card' => [
    'number' => '4242424242424242',
    'exp_month' => 3,
    'exp_year' => 2021,
    'cvc' => '314',
  ],
]);
```

Above code return the card token e.g `tok_***` that you need to use to save card to the customer

Here is the code to create new card to customer

```
\Stripe\Customer::createSource(
  $customer->id,
  ['source' => $token->id]
);
```

You can save customeId(cust_###) and cardId(card_###) in database or somewhere else so you can use it later while making payment from card

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi i have finished above steps and successfully gets both cus_id and card_id and how to use this id's in Stripecheckout.configure

Comment: If you are going witht the stripe default checkout process to make payment, I don't think it will allow you to set or display saved card on page so if you are saving card detail to database than you can create you own custom UI and make payment using `charge`  method of stripe, else you can read this link(https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) that might help you

Comment: Hi Bhargav ,Thanks for above answer  it was saved my day :)